# Rewriting sub directories to Current Directory using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, directory-structure

```
AcceptPathInfo On
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php?req=$1 [L,PT]
```

This is what I have currently. If it isn't obvious, i want to find the current location of the .htaccess file currently being run and change any url that its suppose to hit after the current url to hit /CurrentDirectory/index.php?req=restofurl

Unfortunately, this breaks
However,

```
AcceptPathInfo On
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php?req=$1 [L,PT]
```

Doesn't break and works **exactly** as desired, except hits root directory

Comment: I don't get it. Could you please add real life samples: what the user types in the browser, and how it's internally modified on the server side?

Comment: add it manually like this: RewriteBase /your_directory/

Comment: This is an abuse of the `RewriteBase` directive and could produce bizarre results.  `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` is in the filesystem namespace (e.g. `/var/www`) but the argument to `RewriteBase` is in the URI namespace (e.g. /var/www is often `/`).

Comment: @Oliver I'd prefer to keep the project private

Comment: @machineaddict that can work though I prefer not to due to the nature of making websites and changing directories so often

Comment: @Terry I understand document root a bit better now. that makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like you just want to skip the RewriteBase altogether. Since you want the redirect to be relative to current directory, I'd have thought this would work...

```
RewriteEngine On
RerwiteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php$
RerwiteRule ^(.*) index.php?req=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I gave it a shot, for some reason it doesn't want to play nice.
It gave me an internal server error without much description, looked about right though

Comment: @formula1 FWIW I've been investigating this issue and I'm pretty sure the internal server error is an infinite redirect.  You can find out for sure by checking the Apache error log.  I'm not sure there is a solution to this problem other than setting RewriteBase conditionally based on the server you are at.